# How to design the spinner with custom color and bottom border etc?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to customize the spinner in android. When i add the xml source for spinner it looks like this:

[image]

No border, only down arrow.

But i want to customize it for example like this:

[image]

Please don't make this for me. I just want to learn by my self and want to know what are the various ways to design and customize the spinner. I need to know about all the ways for example by using xml attributes of spinner, or separate xml style file, or xml shape file or with java etc. Further more, after knowing the ways i will design it by myself. A little example with each way will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: you have to add background shape for this.

Comment: But when i do it hides the drop down pin icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding style to the spinner

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined"
/>
```